# SQL SELECT TOP statement is not working properly

Tags: mysql

I am trying to view the first 2 records of a table name `Customers` which have two columns name `Name(varchar)` and `Salary(text)` in MySQL server 6.0
The command which I am using is:

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM customers;
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 8):

**I recommend you to write statement like this using LIMIT**

```
SELECT * FROM customers [WHERE conditions] [ORDER BY expression [ASC|DESC]] LIMIT 2 ;
```

**Instead of**

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM customers;
```

Comment: Hi @Black, please check the following link https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,15082,15312. The TOP command is not supported in MySQL, use instead LIMIT.

Answer (score 3):

Use this in case of MySQL:

```
select * from customers limit 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple. Just try this

```
SELECT * FROM customers LIMIT 2;
```

You can check the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html) also.

Comment: @Black As mentioned in the above question, MySQL does not support it. It's something unique to MS SQL Server/MS Access

Answer (score 1):

To get any position value in the whole tale I suggest you to use the following query as TOP [position] doesn't work in all versions of MySQL.

```
select min(column_name) from (select column_name from table_name order by column_name desc limit position_you_sort) any_name_for_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no keyword **TOP** in MySQL. Instead of using the query:

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM customers;
```

I suggest using the query:

```
SELECT * FROM customers LIMIT 2;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM customer ORDER BY *attribute name* ASC|DESC LIMIT 2;
```

---

Here,
 1. **ASC** represents ascending order.
2. **DESC** represents descending order.
3. *attribute name* is the column name on which the order by clauses works.

For reference of the keywords in MySQL, please refer [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html)